# How to copy new file created by third party application automatically on windows?

Tags: windows, file, copy

Is it possible to copy a new file created by third party application inside a directory automatically on windows?

It goes like:

Third party process 'P' creates a new temporary file 'F' inside a directory 'D'. Whenever this file F is created by the process P, I want to copy this file F into another directory D2. Additional problem is that file F gets deleted by the process P after some time. So cron job won't help.

I think, I need to trap 'new file created' event somehow, if any such thing exists.

Comment: Are you trying do this from the OS itself or are you writing an application for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a program in c# which uses the FileSystemWatcher class.

See: [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Then catch the created event, and copy the file.

Comment: @Bravax: Is there a way to detect 'process killed/terminated'? Then I can terminate my program as soon as third party application quits.

Comment: Though I've accepted this answer since technically it's better but personally I'm going with Jonathan's dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use .NET's [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to monitor a directory for new files.

If you're looking for a more native solution, check out the [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx) family of Win32 functions.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and Dirty: You can run a simple .bat file that contains an infinite loop. Inside the loop [copy](http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm) (with overwrite /y) the content of the directory, and then use the [sleep](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html) command to rest for a while.

This solution is quick to develop and test.

Comment: This one is dirty but awesome

Answer (score 0):

You should create an application that constantly monitors that directory for new files, and moves them as soon as they are created.

There is no "new file created" event to monitor.

Comment: @snicker: That's what I thought. Is there a way to piggyback a process with another one? I mean when process P starts I can start my own process to watch and it ends with P.

Comment: @snicker: how can I detect "moves them as soon as they are created"? I obvious way would be to check directory size after every few seconds.

Comment: You can start your process and terminate if the other process does not exist. In C#, specifically, this can be accomplished by first finding the process by using System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses and then monitoring its state in your main application loop. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses.aspx

Comment: You simply keep a running tally of what was in the directory when you started, and if something new appears, move it. You have to do this at intervals you feel are small enough to capture your elusive file.

Comment: Bravax's answer is much easier for C#.